# jqgrid (version 4.4.1) grids in MVC 4 web pages hangs IE9/10

Tags: internet-explorer, jqgrid, freeze

This is a strange hang problem with jqgrid, version 4.4.1, and IE9/10 in a MVC 4 web app (also happened with MVC 3).

I have many pages with jqgrids on them, and this is a problem with all of them.  Pages work fine in IE when run in development mode (hitting the F5 key), but when they are run from a web server, it hangs the browser.  This is not a problem in Chrome, Safari, or Firefox.

If I turn on the IE JS error display, the following error appears continually, which is why the browser is hanging:

Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 151
Char: 212
Code: 0
URI: .../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1.min.js

Here is a jgrid from one of the hanging pages:

```
$("#GridQuery").jqGrid({
    caption: "Lists",
    colNames: [
        "ID",
        "Select",
        "List Name",
        "Last Import Date",
        "Last Run Date"
        ],
    colModel: [
        { name: "ID", index: "ID",
            hidden: true,
            sortable: false,
            width: 0
        },
        { name: "Select", index: "Select",
            align: "center",
            sortable: false,
            width: 10
        },
        { name: "ListName", index: "ListName",
            sortable: false,
            width: 60
        },
        { name: "LastImportDate", index: "LastImportDate",
            align: "center",
            sortable: false,
            width: 30
        },
        { name: "LastRunDate", index: "LastRunDate",
            align: "center",
            sortable: false,
            width: 30
        }
        ],
    altRows: true,
    altclass: "altGridRows",
    cellEdit: false,
    cellsubmit: "clientArray",
    datatype: "json",
    emptyrecords: "No lists have been defined",
    footerrow: false,
    gridview: true,
    height: "100%",
    mtype: "post",
    pager: "#GridQueryPager",
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    rowNum: 5,
    url: "/App/GetQueryList",
    userDataOnFooter: false,
    viewrecords: true,
    width: 700,

    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: true,
        cell: "cell",
        id: "id",
        userdata: "userdata"
    },

    gridComplete: function () {
        var idList = $("#GridQuery").jqGrid("getDataIDs");
        if (idList) {
            for (var iX = 0; iX < idList.length; iX++) {
                var id = $("#GridQuery").jqGrid("getCell", idList[iX], "ID");
                var checkbox = "<input type='checkbox' id='Check_" + iX + "' />";
                $("#GridQuery").jqGrid("setCell", idList[iX], "Select", checkbox);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you repeat the same test using `jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1.min.js`. The error message `Invalid argument. Line: 151 Char: 212 Code: 0` say nothing with minimized version of jqGrid.

Comment: Additionally I would recommend you to change `id: "id"` to `id: "ID"` inside of `jsonReader` (you can use juse `jsonReader: {id: "ID"}` instead of your current one because values of all othe properties default). It saves `ID` values as rowids. Then you can remove unneeded `ID` column. Why you don't use `formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled: false}` for `"Select"` column? It would make `gridComplete` unneeded and improves the performance. I recommend you remove `index` property from all columns and use `cmTemplate: {align: "center",sortable: false}` because the most columns use it.

Comment: Will try the full source version and try to find the offending line

Comment: In regard to changing the ID column name, I don't want to do that because in some cases I submit a row or the entire grid back to the server, and I need the contents of the ID column in order to process the data.  Therefore, I use a "standard" setup for all of the grids in the app.

Comment: 1) If you use `jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid-4.4.1.min.js` then one can localize the line where the error take place. Posting of errors from `jquery.jqGrid-XXX.min.js` version have mostle no value. 2) jqGrid assign `id` attribute of every row (`<tr>` in the table) to the value which you can specify by `jsonReader: {id: "ID"}`. In the way rowid hwic you will see in every callback and which will be send during editing to the server will be the value of `ID`. So no additional ID column are required. You can add `prmNames: {id: "ID"}` additionally.

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with the page displaying correctly in IE local but not from webserver. I added the code in _layout.cshtml, head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5, IE=8, IE=9, IE=10" >
```

Which helped ony my case. Hope that will help you

Thanks

Comment: What specifically did you add?